# Replace primary key created by devise with my own created attribute

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am new to rails. I am creating an application using **devise gem**. I made user model using gem and views and controller everything.
But i faced an issue. I create an extra field in user model name User_ID and i want to make it primary key. But devise already created one in **postgres database** so i am enable to create it.

Please, can someone help me in this how to make my **extra field** **primary key** instead of the one devise created.

Please help me in this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may want to try this In your migration file

```
class AddUserIdToUsers < ActiveRecordMigration[5.0] 
def change add_column users, 
user_id, integer 
end 
end
```

And then in your model

```
class User < ActiveRecordBase 
self.primary_key = "user_id" 
end
```

Comment: I did this but get error that you cannot make two primary key for one table